# read JSON data received from the mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to read data in the javascript which is received from the server in JSON format.

I've been using this a lot, but now it seems that I hit the wall with this example:

**JSON**

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "MIN(jtable.HIT_VALUE)": "70.200000",
            "AVG(jtable.HIT_VALUE)": "124.4077234969",
            "MAX(jtable.HIT_VALUE)": "1854.620000"
        }
    ]

}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

How to read these values?

I have tried this

```
response.results[i].MIN(jtable.HIT_VALUE)
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'MIN'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `results[i]['MIN(jtable.HIT_VALUE)']`

Comment: USE ALAISES IN MYSQL query like min(table.hitvalue) as minhitvalue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E3UdM/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MIN(jtable.HIT_VALUE)` is the key and has to be used as such using the square bracket notation like

```
response.results[i]['MIN(jtable.HIT_VALUE)']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it as string:

```
response.results[i]['MIN(jtable.HIT_VALUE)']
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript interprets the call `response.results[i].MIN(jtable.HIT_VALUE)` as an attempt to call a nonexistent function `MIN`.

Consider using this:

```
response.results[i]["MIN(jtable.HIT_VALUE)"]
```